# redistemplate exceptions after redis server restart

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, jedis

Using redisTemplate, things work until redis server restart. Then two exceptions occur (see below).

When I stop using `redisTemplate.executePipelined`, the exception  2 stops happening. After invoking `redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(false);`, the exception 1 goes away.

But I have no idea why.

Any ideas?

Exception 1:

```
    org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.ex
    ceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:67)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:41)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:212)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2890)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.hGetAll(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:360)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:223)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:204)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:166)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:88)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
            ....
    Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
            at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:104)
            at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:84)
            at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:127)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.hgetAll(BinaryClient.java:294)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.hgetAll(BinaryJedis.java:1027)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2888)
            ... 14 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flushBuffer(RedisOutputStream.java:52)
            at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.write(RedisOutputStream.java:59)
            at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:90)
            ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Exception 2:

```
            org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot use Jedis when in Pipeline. Please use Pipeline or reset jedis state .; nested
     exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: Cannot use Jedis when in Pipeline. Please use Pipeline or reset jedis state .
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:64)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:41)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:212)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2890)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.hGetAll(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:360)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:223)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations$13.doInRedis(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:204)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:166)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:88)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:220)
            ...
    Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: Cannot use Jedis when in Pipeline. Please use Pipeline or reset jedis state .
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.checkIsInMultiOrPipeline(BinaryJedis.java:1761)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.hgetAll(BinaryJedis.java:1026)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.hGetAll(JedisConnection.java:2888)
            ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you use connection pooling with Jedis? If not, then give it a try. Alternatively, try the lettuce client.

Comment: yes and set testOnBorrow=true at the beginning.

Comment: The first exception indicates some network/process issues. Jedis tries to read from the TCP connection while the server has already closed it. You might want to check the timeout setting in your Redis server. Alternatively, investigate why the server closes the connection while your client keeps it open.

Comment: testOnBorrow=ture,but can't find the connection is broken until call
`redis.clients.jedis.Connection.RedisOutputStream.flush`, find by debug.and why i setEnableTransactionSupport=false, the exception stop happening,i think it's redistemplate's bug or i am using in the wrong way.